# I got an error when updateing the gradle plugin to 2.0.0

Tags: android, gradle

my configuration is as below:

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

**gradle plugin is 2.0.0**

but i got this error:

```
Exception while inflating <vector>
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0
```

i've tried this:

```
 //for Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: post your vector drawable

Comment: i find that it's nothing about the gradle. my app runs ok on meizu cellphone,but got this error on huawei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my gradle build tool is 1.3.1. my solution is to add

```
aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
}
```

outside the `defaultConfig{}` and it works